# Find absolute max and min on $[-1, 4]$

Tags: calculus

Find absolute max and min. Given interval $[-1,4]$

$f(t) = t - \sqrt[3]{t}$

So far, I've done the derivative

$f'(t)= 1 - \frac{1}{3t^{2/3}}$

The next step would be to find the critical number but I got stuck because I simplified my equation to:

$f'(t)= \frac{3t^{2/3}-1}{3t^{2/3}}$

I got stuck on this particular part of the problem:

$3t^{2/3} - 1 = 0$

Comment: Add 1, divide by 3, make a square and take a cube root.

Comment: $$ 3t^{\frac{2}{3}} - 1 = 0 $$
$$ 3t^{\frac{2}{3}} = 1 $$
$$ t^{\frac{2}{3}} = \frac{1}{3} $$
$$ t ^{\frac{1}{3}} = ({\frac{1}{3}})^3 = \frac{1}{27} $$
$$ t = \sqrt{\frac{1}{27}} = \frac{1}{3\sqrt{3}} $$

Comment: Don't forget that checking where the derivative is $0$ on $[a,b]$ only gives you local minima and maxima on the interval $(a,b)$. Hence you need to compare the minima and maxima you find this way to $f(a)$ and $f(b)$. Also note that the derivative at a point being zero does not imply by itself that there is a local maximum/minimum there: see $x \mapsto x^3$ at $x = 0$.

Answer (score 2):

From where you left off: $t^{\frac{2}{3}} = \dfrac{1}{3} \implies t = \left(\dfrac{1}{3}\right)^{\frac{3}{2}}= \dfrac{1}{3\sqrt{3}}$. Can you take it from  here? Another way to solve this if you don't like fractional exponent is making a substitution: $x = \sqrt[3]{t} \implies t = x^3$. Thus you find the min and max of the function $f(x) = x^3 - x $ on $[-1,\sqrt[3]{4}]$.

Comment: So Once I find the critical number(s). I plug in the interval endpoints and critical number to the original function, right? And from that point I just compare the values